# MaxMind - Server blocking access

Tags: wordpress, geolocation, maxmind

This is the first time I am making use of Stack Overflow, so hopefully I'll be doing this all right. And, thanks in advance for reading this!

I have a small issue, we have a WordPress website that's making use of the MaxMind GEO Location API which we are using to hide a certain call to action on a shop page. It was working 100% fine, but then after a few days, it stopped working.

We tried a few things but nothing worked, so the last thing we did was make a clone of the site and migrated to another host to see if that helped, which it did. So we now know it is server related.

I have contacted my hosts and they say it's very possible that their servers are blocking content or feeds etc, but have asked if I could provide information to help them track down the issue.

They asked specifically if MaxMind has a certain IP address and or URL it useless in their API feed when calling the data. Would anyone here have any idea what it could be or where one could obtain this data?

I have looked online bit not been able to find anything concrete.
I hope you can help, and thanks in advance.

I have disabled all server-side caching, CDN and the likes.
Used the default WordPress theme and disabled any and all plugins.
The only thing that worked was using a different server.

Expecting the website to work with GEO location and hide/show call to action to the frontend of the website depending on the users location.

Comment: Do you use a plugin to hit MaxMind? If so, which one? If not, please show us the code you use. Also, it might be good to enable WP_DEBUG and WP_DEBUG_LOG, then try the failing operation, then look at wp_content/debug.log to see if you can find a useful error message,

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment and sorry, not even sure why I didn't give those details! Yes, using Elementor Pro with the UAE plugin to enable the GEO Location filters. (https://ultimateelementor.com)

Comment: I also informed my server provider about the IP address, thanks for that.
They however came back with the following feedback:
- - - -
I've just checked for those IP addresses making any connections to us today, and there's been no hits at all. 

Only thing I can think of at the moment is that it might be hitting our mod sec rules, as I can see 2 entries trying to access xmlrpc.php despite our whitelisting, but the user agent used indicated that a human visitor tried to access via a browser ("Mozilla"), is that a user agent that maxmind uses? 
- - - 
Unfortunately didnt help it seems. :(

Comment: This remark from your host is about *incoming* requests. But your failure may be due to a blocked *outgoing* web request from code on your server to MaxMind. Or you may have hit a limit on MaxMind or had your account expire or something.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how to handle this. The only thing I could think of doing was making a clone and testing on another server and that worked 100% fine. I also created another MaxMind API Key and tested it on both the live server and the cloned one. On the cloned one it worked as expected again, yet on the live side it didn't work as before. So I don't believe its any limit from MaxMind's side, also, this website gets maybe 100 visitors a day, and not all those go to the page where the GEO location is needed/triggered. Just wondering how one tackles this, as I'm 90% sure its server related.

Comment: See my first comment. Enable debugging. Look for messages.

Comment: Sorry, I had actually looked when you mentioned it. I saw a few logs, but nothing pertaining to the issue. Went to the page a few times on different browsers, and tried to refresh the page and use it for a while, but no error/s got logged during that process.

Answer (score 0):

You can find MaxMind's server IP addresses [here](https://dev.maxmind.com/maxmind-server-ip-addresses). You can ask many hosting providers to add them to their allow-list for outbound web requests from the server machines they operate.

Most SaaS vendors offering web-service endpoints the way MaxMind does will have lists like this.